# Fatal error encountered during mysql command execution

Tags: c#, mysql

> Error: Fatal error encountered during command execution.

I have tried other changes recommended in other posts but it still not working. 
Where am I going wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Following is my code for insert value into MYSQL db.
There are quite a number of parameters, some are in textbox (txt_name), combobox (combo_name) and datetimepicker (dtp_name)

```
private void savebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=server; user id=db1; password=password; database=db");
    string query =
        @"INSERT INTO table (
            CALID, DEPT, PROC_AREA, SERVICE_TYPE,
            SERIALNO, PARTNAME, PART_NO, OEM, CAL_INTERVAL,
            DUE_DATE, TARGET, CAL_REQ, SAP, SITE,
            MOD_OWNER, QTY, SAP_FUNCLOC, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE)
         VALUES (
            @CALID, @DEPT, @PROC_AREA, @SERVICE_TYPE,
            @SERIALNO, @PARTNAME, @PART_NO, @OEM, @CAL_INTERVAL,
            @DUE_DATE, @TARGET, @CAL_REQ, @SAP, @SITE,
            @MOD_OWNER, @QTY, @SAP_FUNCLOC, @CREATED_BY, @CREATED_DATE)";

    cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CALID",txt_CalID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEPT", combo_Dept.SelectedItem);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROC_AREA", combo_Area.SelectedItem);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SERVICE_TYPE", combo_ServiceType.SelectedItem);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SERIALNO", txt_SerialNo.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PARTNAME", txt_PartName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PART_NO", txt_Model.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OEM", txt_OEM.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAL_INTERVAL", combo_Interval.SelectedItem);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DUE_DATE", dtp_duedate.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TARGET", txt_Target.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAL_REQ", combo_CalReq.SelectedItem);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SAP", combo_SAP.SelectedItem);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SITE", combo_Site.SelectedItem);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MOD_OWNER", txt_Owner.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QTY", txt_Qty.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SAP_FUNLOC", txt_FunLoc.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREATED_BY", txt_CreatedBy.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREATED_DATE", dtp_CreatedDate.Value);

    try
    {
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data Not Inserted");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO db` - what is "db", your table mane? Because `insert into` should be followed by table name

Comment: `INSERT INTO db`   is `db` table name?

Comment: what is the table name?

Comment: I am aware that to include table name after INSERT INTO, I've edited the code from `INSERT INTO db` to `INSERT INTO table`, to make it less confuse.

Comment: I am using MySQL, so change it to this  `cmd.Parameters.Add("@CALID", MySqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = txt_CalID.Text;` am I right ?

Comment: sorry, since you are using MySQL then the format is right.. what you need to do now is to check  all parameters value, check if they have value and in right datatype

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the error is...

Comment: Look at your connections string. And look at the parameters posted in MySql documentation --> `"server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=12345;database=test"`

Comment: Another thing is, `AddWithValue` is not a very good way to set parameters. And in your case, if you use  `AddWithValue` with `combo.SelectedItem`, `SelectedItem` is object. It is better explicitly set value - `AddWithValue("@DEPT", (string)combo_Dept.SelectedItem)`. If your selected item is some sort of object, do `AddWithValue("@DEPT", ((MyType)combo.SelectedItem).MyTypeProperty)`.

Comment: Another thing, you don't want to do `if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)`. You should do `if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)` because any given table can have a trigger. In other words, `ExecuteNonQuery` for plain sql returns total number of rows returned. A single call may cause changes to more than 1 row.